# Create tuple text file from text file selecting every three consecutive rows

Tags: python, tuples

I have text file with following data:

```
AAA
111
A1A1
BBB
222
B2B2
CCC
333
C3C3
```

Reading text file I need to create new text file which would contain tuples:

```
(AAA,111,A1A1)
(BBB,222,B2B2)
(CCC,333,C3C3)
```

The function has to select every three consecutive row and create tuple out of selection.

Comment: What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contentList = open('source.txt','r').readlines()
outFile = open('outfile.txt','w')

start , end , step = 0 , 3, 3 
while end <= len(contentList):
  eml1,eml2,eml3 = (contentList[start:end])
  writeString = '( '+eml1.rstrip('\n')+','+ eml2.rstrip('\n') +','+ eml3.rstrip('\n') +' )'
  outFile.write(writeString)
  outFile.write('\n')
  start = start + step
  end = end + step

outFile.close()
```

**RESULT**

```
# cat outfile.txt
( AAA,111,A1A1 )
( BBB,222,B2B2 )
( CCC,333,C3C3 )

# cat course.txt
AAA
111
A1A1
BBB
222
B2B2
CCC
333
C3C3
```

Comment: The code works. Thanks for soon reply.

Comment: I am happy to know that my code has helped.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
original = file("original.txt", "r")
lines = original.read().split("\n")
original.close()
result = file("result.txt", "a")
for n in range(0, len(lines), 3):
    result.write("(" + ",".join(lines[n:n+3]) + ")\n")
result.close()
```

---

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/Kq1smR)

Comment: The code works. I missed len(lines) method to include in range. Thank you!

Comment: Most elegant solution here! :) 
Completely forgot about range increments.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. The code is written so that the file containing information is called 'source.txt' and it outputs to a file called 'Output.txt'.

```
OutputFile = open("Output.txt", 'w')
InputLines = open('source.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")


line = "("
for index in range(len(InputLines)):
    line += InputLines[index]
    if ((index+1) % 3 == 0): # if this is the third element
        OutputFile.write(line + ")\n")
        line = "(" # reinitialises the variable
    else:
        line += ", "

OutputFile.close()
```

Comment: The code works. Thanks.